# Installing Boehm's C garbage collector on os x mavericks

Tags: macos, failed-installation, boehm-gc

i'm trying to install a c garbage collector on my mac. I have downloaded all necessary files (git, automake etc). I follow the instruction from the site http://www.hboehm.info/gc/. When i reach the command "automake --add-missing" i get the following message:

```
configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
automake: error: no 'Makefile.am' found for any configure output
automake: Did you forget AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile]) in configure.ac?
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the wrong version of automake -- make sure that you have the *exact* version specified by the software and not any later version, as later versions of automake are not generally backwards compatible.

Comment: I don't think it's automake's fault. I have version 1.14.1 installed on both my mac and my ubuntu laptop. On ubuntu i successfully installed the garbage collector following the instructions. On mac i get an error.